# AirPort Base-station Visibility

Tags: network, airport

I bought an AirPort Extreme to use in my college apartment. The ISP is technically my university, so the device is set in "bridge" mode to avoid double NAT errors. When I check the network diagram when firing up AirPort Utility, however, I can see other AirPorts that my classmates are using in their rooms.  I want to know if it is possible to hide my AirPort from them so they cannot see mine like I can see theirs.  People get bored and nosey at the university.

Technically I cannot access their devices because they are password protected and so is my device but I would like to be safer if I can.

Answer (score 1):

Someone can downvote, edit or comment if I'm wrong on this, but I don't believe this is possible.

Normally, you can only see the AirPort from inside the private network, and by default it doesn't advertise or allow configuration on the outside interface (i.e. the internet). Because you're using bridge mode, though, there's no distinction between the networks. To prevent it from advertising its existence, you'd have to disable Bonjour entirely on it. The utility doesn't have an option for this, as far as I can see.